# QGIS visible window rendering

Tags: qgis, rendering

Is there a way of changing the rendering settings on QGIS so that only the visible map extent renders? It seems that all layers are rendered to the full layer extent. I'm trying to speed rendering up and have changed any settings in settings>options>rendering which I thought would help (including simplification, caching etc) and they have had an impact, but thought the visible window functionality would be helpful. Does it exist?

Comment: QGIS should behave as you wish if your source data come from PostGIS.

Comment: If you are dealing with a vector layer, did you create a spatial index (Layer properties windows > General tab > Create a spatial index)? This should speed up the rendering.

Comment: User30184 - Useful to know though unfortunately not in PostGIS this time.